# How to create calendar with events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar

Hello i'm trying to make event calendar . 
Maybe somebody give me idea how to because i dont know how to customize calendar I lost about 2-3 days and didn't do anything 
Tried to customize fullcalendar and nothing . 
I hope on your support
Thanks

Calendar image what i need:

[image]

Comment: You'll receive more help if you post more detail about what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: I just need event calendar 
where digits - amount of events on this day 
i found calendars with functionality what i need but i can't customize him 
how to put this image into 
thats what i need

Answer (score 0):

I've added a similar method to this [date-picker](https://github.com/alihaghighatkhah/Pikaday/blob/master/pikaday.js#L407). it's easy to use. you still need to make a change in stylesheets because I didn't have time. but it gives you the idea how to start.

How to use it?

```
var datePicker = new Pikaday({
            field: document.getElementById('date-picker'),
            onSelect: (newDate) => {
                // Here you can update this day with setSecondaryConfig method

            },
            onMonthChange: (year: number, month: number) => {
                // here you can call for labels for this month using setSecondaryConfig method
            },
            onOpen: () => {
                // or here you can fetch labels for the first month being shown 
            }
        });
```

This works fine with sync API calls.